# Jquery automatically trigger function within if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this bit of jquery that slowly reveals the h1 tag (for demo purposes, this isn't the purpose of the code). So I know the scrolling portion is working. And I can click to initiate the function but I can't automatically trigger it. I'm sure it's something simple and stupid that I'm not seeing.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
     var hT = jQuery('#scroll-to').offset().top,
     hH = jQuery('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
     wH = jQuery(window).height(),
     wS = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
  if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)) {
     jQuery('#scroll-to').fadeIn(3500); // this test works
     div.onclick = labnolIframe; // this works
     div.trigger('labnolIframe'); // this doesn't
   }
});

function labnolIframe() {
// does stuff
}

<h1 id="scroll-to">I am The H1</h1>
```

Comment: This is the testing page: http://www.scosche.com/baseclamp

Comment: Looks like `.trigger()` is just for events (click and such) -- plus you're passing a string instead of an object/function.  Instead of `div.trigger('labnolIframe'); ` try `labnolIframe()`

Comment: trigger() is similar to on() which binds only for click kind of events

Comment: Thank you for the response @Doug sadly though it didn't work :(

Comment: @Abhishek do you have any suggestions of what I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out thanks to the following post:  https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/call-a-function-in-a-if-statement-banging-my-head/6382/3

```
if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){

    labnolIframe.call(div); // This works!
}
```